# My object looks black rather than transparent

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, shadows

How to obtain a perfectly transparent rendering? My object is composed of black material on the rendering that I would not like. Can I work on the light path in order to get a more transparent rendering ? Thanks

[image: My screen settings]

[image: How my material looks]

[image: My rendering]

EDIT 1

@susu , thank you for your respond, yes sure here it is :

[image]

EDIT 2

Thank you, I have tried and do not quite get the desired result, there is black in my material again

[image]

I would like the result to be close to that:

[image]

Thank you :)

EDIT 3

@lookin thank you :) i have done it but the result isn't quite what i wanted (the object on top is the one with your node tree)

[image]

Comment: It makes no sense to add shaders the way you are adding them. Use the principled shader only and explore the settings for transmission and alpha.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a more transparent material, use a Transparent BSDF shader instead of a Glass BSDF.

I mean this kind of node tree:
[image]

Comment: there is no need for an additional shader, the principled shader can do alpha directly.

Comment: @susu yes you're right!